# I am having syntax error in Flex/Bison for a C- program

Tags: c, compiler-construction, bison, flex-lexer

I was doing my project for my compilers lessons, I finally finished it and it compilers but I keep getting a syntax error, and I don't know why! I tried using differences sources to see what I can find but nothing really helped. I even tried ChatGPT, so I came here to ask for advice and see what I am doing wrong from people that might know.

lab1.fl

```
%{
    #include "lab1.tab.h"
    int line = 1; //what line are we on in the code
    char filename[20];
    
    int comment = 0;
    
    int yywrap(void) {
    return 1;
    }
    
%}

ID      [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*
NUM     [0-9]+

%%



"\n" {return 0;}

"//"(.)*"\n" {}
"/*" { comment=1; printf("multiline comment\n");}
"*/" {comment=0;}



"int"                  { if (!comment) return INT; }
"void"                 { if (!comment) return VOID; }
"if"                    { if (!comment) return IF; }
"else"                  { if (!comment) return ELSE; }
"while"                 { if (!comment) return WHILE; }
"return"                { if (!comment) return RETURN; }

{ID}                    { yylval.strval = strdup(yytext); if (!comment) return ID; }
{NUM}                   { if (!comment) return NUM; }

"=="                    { if (!comment) return EQ; }
"!="                    { if (!comment) return NE; }
"<="                    { if (!comment) return LE; }
">="                    { if (!comment) return GE; }
"<"                     { if (!comment) return LT; }
">"                     { if (!comment) return GT; }

"+"                     { if (!comment) return ADD; }
"-"                     { if (!comment) return SUB; }
"*"                     { if (!comment) return MUL; }
"/"                     { if (!comment) return DIV; }

"("                     { if (!comment) return LPAREN; }
")"                     { if (!comment) return RPAREN; }
"["                     { if (!comment) return LBRACKET; }
"]"                     { if (!comment) return RBRACKET; }
"{"                     { if (!comment) return LBRACE; }
"}"                     { if (!comment) return RBRACE; }
","                     { if (!comment) return COMMA; }
";"                     { if (!comment) return SEMICOLON; }
"="                     { if (!comment) return ASSIGN; }
[\t| \r | \f | \v]      {}
<<EOF>>                 {return 0;}
%%

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
    if (argc==2)
        yyin = fopen(argv[1], "rt");
    else
    {
        printf("No file-Exit\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    strcpy(filename,argv[1]);
    yylex();
    yyparse();
    fclose(yyin);
}
```

lab1.y

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int yylex();
void yyerror(char *s);

#define YYSTYPE_IS_DECLARED
#define YYSTYPE_IS_TRIVIAL 1

typedef struct {
    int numval;      // For NUM
    char *strval;    // For ID
} YYSTYPE;

#include "lab1.tab.h"
%}

%token INT VOID IF ELSE WHILE RETURN
%token <strval> ID 
%token <numval> NUM
%token EQ NE LT LE GT GE ADD SUB MUL DIV
%token LPAREN RPAREN LBRACKET RBRACKET LBRACE RBRACE COMMA SEMICOLON ASSIGN

%union {
  char *strval;  // Define the type of the semantic value
}

%type <strval> type_specifier
%type <strval> var
%type <strval> call
%type <strval> args
%type <strval> arg_list

%nonassoc LOWER_THAN_ELSE  
%left ADD SUB              
%left MUL DIV              
%nonassoc EQ NE            
%nonassoc LT LE GT GE      

%start program

%%

program: {printf("Program \n declaration_list\n");} declaration_list

declaration_list: declaration_list declaration {printf("declaration_list\n");}
                | declaration {printf("declaration ");}
                ;
declaration: var_declaration {printf("var declaration\n");}
                | fun_declaration {printf("fun declaration\n");}
                
var_declaration: type_specifier ID SEMICOLON {printf("variable_declaration(INT)");} 
                | type_specifier ID ASSIGN NUM SEMICOLON {printf("type_specifier(INT)\n"); printf("variable_declaration\n");}

type_specifier: INT {printf("type_specifier(INT)\n");}
                | VOID {printf("type_specifier(VOID)\n");}

fun_declaration: type_specifier ID LPAREN params RPAREN compound_stmt {printf("fun_definition");}

params: param_list
                | VOID {printf("params(VOID)\n");}

param_list: param_list COMMA param {printf("tparams list\n");} |
                param {printf("params list");}

param: type_specifier ID {printf("params(%s)\n",$2);} | type_specifier ID LBRACE RBRACE {printf("params{$s [])\n",$2);}

compound_stmt: LPAREN local_declarations statement_list RPAREN {printf("compound_stmt\n");}

local_declarations: local_declarations var_declaration {printf("local declaration\n");} | /* empty */

statement_list: statement_list statement {printf("statement list\n");} | /* empty */

statement: expression_stmt {printf("expression statement\n");} 
                | compound_stmt {printf("compound statement\n");} 
                | selection_stmt {printf("selection statement\n");}
                | iteration_stmt {printf("iteration statement\n");}
                | return_stmt {printf("return statement\n");}

expression_stmt: expression SEMICOLON | SEMICOLON

selection_stmt: IF LPAREN expression RPAREN statement %prec LOWER_THAN_ELSE | IF LPAREN expression RPAREN statement ELSE statement

iteration_stmt: WHILE LPAREN  expression RPAREN statement 

return_stmt: RETURN SEMICOLON | RETURN expression SEMICOLON

expression: var ASSIGN expression {printf("expression \n");}| simple_expression {printf("simple expression\n");}

var: ID {printf("var(%s)\n",$1);} | ID expression {printf("var(%s)\n",$1);}

simple_expression: additive_expression relop additive_expression {printf("additive expression\n");} | additive_expression {printf("additive expression\n");}

relop: EQ | NE | LE | GE | LT | GT

additive_expression: additive_expression addop term  | term

addop: ADD | SUB

term: term mulop factor {printf("term\n");} | factor {printf("term\n");}

mulop: MUL | DIV

factor: var | call | NUM

call: ID LPAREN args RPAREN

args: arg_list {printf("args list\n");} | /* empty */ {$$ = NULL;}

arg_list:  arg_list COMMA expression | expression {$$ = NULL;} | /* empty */ {$$ = NULL;}


%%

void yyerror(char *s) {
    printf("%s",s);
}
```

I use an input.txt file to run the program but even a blank program doesn't work
even if I only insert a `int a;` for example into it, still nothing

I was expecting a syntax tree from my program but I only get the declaration_list and everything else doesn't work and I get a syntax error.

EDIT: I found the issue being that it doesn't return the tokens to the parser for some reason, I am still trying to figure out the issue, if anyone can help!

Comment: Start ***small***, with only like one single and simple rule. Once tested to make sure it works, add another. And so on. That makes it much easier to figure out when and where things go wrong.

Comment: I also recommend you develop the lexer and the parser separately. Same thing as above, start small and add after testing.

Comment: And my last recommendation is to keep track of the line numbers, so you can report the correct line number when you get errors in the input.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We do not write answers here that "find the bug"; we require a **specific** question - which will come out of your best attempt to [understand](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/) and [locate](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05) a specific problem, and showcase it in a [mre]. A question that is suitable for Stack Overflow is one where you have already figured out the **specific part** of the code that does something different from what you expect (and you should concretely *expect something*), and don't understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the issue with the tokens, I was using both yylex() and yyparse() but I found out that the parser also does yylex by itself so I removed it and it finally worked.

Comment: You mean it *calls* `yylex()`.

Answer (score 1):

When you get a newline, you `return 0`.

This `0` token is never handled anywhere in the parser.

You should simply ignore it, not return anything at all, like you do for your other space characters.

Comment: I've tried that, I am still having the same issue, it displays only like this:
```
$ ./project.exe input.txt
Program
 declaration_list
syntax error
```

Comment: @GabrielVasile Then create a small program which tests the lexer in isolation. Make sure it returns the tokens you expect. Once it's tested and works, simplify your parser, basically to plain `program: INT;` and nothing more. Test to make sure it works. When it passes all possible tests, add something small and simple, and test again. Continue until you get a problem, which can the much more easily be isolated and tested and debugged.

Comment: I have found one of my issue, I usually compile my bison file as `bison -dy lab1.y` which leads to it being a y.tab.h file instead, I had an old lab1.tab.h when I used to do it only with -d. I have fixed the issue and changed the inclusion to the y.tab.h file. now, the issue still persist with the syntax error. I tried adding a variable declaration into {} but I still get a syntax error at the end